# Empty Array in Controller ...but works in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, console

I'm baffled...

I have a model called Distributor and when I do Distributor.all in the console I get the array of all the records as I should (there are currently 657 records in there according to this query).

However, I created a controller action to show this distributors in an index view. And an empty array is returned from the same query Distributor.all

- I've restarted the server
- I've checked for spelling mistakes (literally copied and pasted the Distributor.all from controller to
  console to make sure and it worked in console)
- I've used binding.pry to debug and no problems are showing there
- I've checked the logs and no errors are showing up
- I've checked the logs vs the console and the same SQL query is being run Distributor Load (10.9ms)  SELECT "distributors".* FROM "distributors" for both, but returning different results
- generating the CSV or HTML isn't a problem because both load without errors

Any suggestions?

Distributor Model:

```
class Distributor < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :brand

def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{distributor_id mfg_brand_id company_name address_one address_two city state postcode country address_type primary_address users_count created_at}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
        csv << attributes

        all.each do |d|
            csv << d.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
        end
    end
  end   
end
```

Distributors Controller

```
class DistributorsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def index
    @user = current_user
    if @user.admin?
      @distributors = Distributor.all

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv { send_data @distributors.to_csv }
      end

    else
     flash["danger"] = "You must be a logged in Admin to  access this route"
     redirect_to root_path
    end
  end   
end
```

Distributors index.html.erb

```
<h1>Distributors#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/distributors/index.html.erb</p>


<%= @distributors.each do |d| %>
    <%= d %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is `RheemruudDistributor` ?

Comment: sorry that shouldn't have been in there. It is Distributor.all (it says Distributor.all in the code, I just typed it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, if you replace `@distributors = RheemruudDistributor.all` with `@distributors = Distributor.all` it should work, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: sorry that shouldn't have been in there. It is Distributor.all (it says Distributor.all in the code, I just typed it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out...and I figured it was something simple.

This is a multi-tenant app using the apartment gem and I had to put this newly created model in the excluded models part of the apartment.rb initializer.

Figured I'd leave this hear in case anyone else is in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<% @distributors.each do |d| %>
    <%= d %>
<% end %>
```

instead of

```
<%= @distributors.each do |d| %>
    <%= d %>
<% end %>
```

on your view